# Can't use React hooks on Next Header

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, scroll

This is my website https://atmos-app-p6hi7.ondigitalocean.app/ I need to decrease the padding on the header when the user scroll for that I do this component :

```
    import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { GET_HEADER, getInfo } from '@/api/api'
import Submenu from './parts/Submenu'
import Burguer from './parts/Burguer'
import HeaderContainer from './parts/HeaderContainer'

export default async function Header() {
  const info = await getInfo(GET_HEADER)
  if (info === null || info === undefined) return null
  const dataHead = info.data?.header.data.attributes.links || []

  return (
    <HeaderContainer>
      <ul className='flex lg:hidden justify-between px-4 items-center'>
        <Link href='/'>
          {' '}
          <Image
            src='/images/logo.svg'
            width='140'
            height='140'
            alt='LogoHeader'
          />{' '}
        </Link>
        <Burguer dropdown={dataHead} />
      </ul>
      <ul className='hidden lg:flex justify-around items-center px-6'>
        {dataHead.map((link, i) => {
          const { title, href, index, dropdown, external_link } = link

          if (index) {
            return (
              <Link key={i} href={href}>
                {' '}
                <Image
                  src='/images/logo.svg'
                  width={150}
                  height={150}
                  alt='LogoHeader'
                />{' '}
              </Link>
            )
          }

          if (dropdown.length > 0) {
            return <Submenu key={i} title={title} dropdown={dropdown} />
          }

          return (
            <Link
              key={i}
              href={href ? href : ''}
              className='text-white hover:text-gray-300 transition duration-300'
              target={external_link ? '_blank' : '_self'}
            >
              {title}
            </Link>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </HeaderContainer>
  )
}
```

On the HeaderContainer I use some React Hooks like that:

```
'use client'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const HeaderContainer = ({ children }) => {
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false)
  console.log(window.scrollY)

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 50) {
        setScrolled(true)
      } else {
        setScrolled(false)
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <header
      className={`${
        scrolled ? 'py-10 lg:py-8' : 'py-16 lg:py-14'
      } fixed top-[-0.25rem] lg:top-0 lg:ml-[-1rem] bg-[url(/images/menu_desktop.svg)] bg-no-repeat text-xl bg-cover bg-center w-screen lg:w-[105%] z-[500]`}
    >
      <nav className='container mx-auto'>{children}</nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default HeaderContainer
```

But it gives me the following error: "Unhandled runtime error
Error: async/await is not yet supported on client components, only server components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding "use client" to a module that was originally written for the server.

I don't know why, I use client only on children, not parents when I need to use server side. Anybody knows how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering, "async/await is not yet supported on client components," is because you're using an asynchronous function (`async function Header()`) in a client-side component. In Next.js, asynchronous operations like `await` are not supported in client-side components by default.

To achieve your goal of decreasing the padding on the header when the user scrolls, you should fetch the data you need on the server side or during server-side rendering (SSR) and pass it as props to your component.

Here's a high-level overview of how you can refactor your code:

1. Move the data fetching logic to a separate function, preferably in a server-side file (e.g., a `getServerSideProps` function in a page file).
2. Pass the fetched data as a prop to your `Header` component.
3. Modify your `Header` component to receive the data as a prop and use it to render the header.

Here's a simplified example:

```
// In your page file (e.g., pages/index.js)
import Header from '../components/Header';

// Implement getServerSideProps to fetch data on the server side.
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const info = await getInfo(GET_HEADER);
  const dataHead = info?.data?.header.data.attributes.links || [];

  return {
    props: {
      dataHead,
    },
  };
}

// Pass the fetched data as a prop to the Header component.
export default function Home({ dataHead }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header dataHead={dataHead} />
      {/* Rest of your page content */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And in your `Header` component:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Submenu from './parts/Submenu';
import Burguer from './parts/Burguer';
import HeaderContainer from './parts/HeaderContainer';

export default function Header({ dataHead }) {
  // Your component logic remains the same, but use dataHead instead of fetching it.

  return (
    <HeaderContainer>
      {/* Render your header using dataHead */}
    </HeaderContainer>
  );
}
```

By following this pattern, you ensure that the data fetching happens on the server side, and you pass the fetched data as props to your client-side components, avoiding the error you encountered.

Comment: Very good, you answer  fix my issue, thanks!

Comment: It's just a copy-paste from ChatGPT though